# How to create a link if you only know the domain

Tags: html, anchor

I want to create a link using anchor tag to a url that I only know the domain of.

For example if I type "twitter.com" into the addressbar of my browser, it would take me to https://twitter.com. I want to something similar to this with an anchor tag. I want to have something like  and be it a link to https://twitter.com.

If I try the above example, it takes me to mydomain.com/twitter.com, which is not I want.

Are there any way I could do this?

Question clarification:

Right now, I have a domain that I want to link to using anchor tags, so I just did . When I click that link, it does not take me to the website "exampledomain.com", but it instead takes me to "mydomain.com/exampledomain.com". I want the link to take me to exmpledomain.com. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `http://` or `https` before the domain name:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/">twitter</a>
```

If you want more information about the `a` tag, take a look at the [Anchor Element page on w3school.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) You can go further and see how does the `href` attribute work:

> [HTML  href Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)
>
> ```
> Value     Description
> URL       The URL of the link.
>
>             Possible values:
>                  - An absolute URL - points to another web site (like href="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
>                  - A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like href="default.htm")
>                  - Link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top")
>                  - Other protocols (like https://, ftp://, mailto:, file:, etc..)
>                  - A script (like href="javascript:alert('Hello');")
> ```

Comment: What if I don't know if it's a http or https website?

Comment: Websites using HTTPS tend to enforce its use, generally by redirecting the users to the HTTPS webpage. However, if one of them doesn't redirect the users, I don't know a better way than to check manually.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot link to site without adding an protocol to it, because url can have any number of protocols.

Event if link would work without protocol value. For instance, in layout below:

```
<a href="//twitter.com">Go twitter</a>
```

Link would replace your  current page `protocol://address` to  `protocol://twitter.com`

So if your current page fetched with `http` you would be pointed to http://twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with a framework of any sort?
That might be an issue where the framework is using a base-url or some sort and that's why he is sending you to mydomain.com/twitter.com, instead of simply twitter.com